# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una lista con más de 3000 objetos sin que se cicle todo el sitio web en ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Quiero mostrar una lista de productos desde una base de datos usando un repetidor. El problema es que cuando trato de cargar más de 100 productos queda trabada la página y temo que si cargo más termine cerrándose todo.

Asi solamente muestro 100 artículos, pero si le quito el `take(100)` quedaría trabada.

¿Qué otra forma hay de traerme la lista de la base de datos?

```
public List<articulo> ListaCompleta
{
    get
    {
        toolcribEntities te = new toolcribEntities();
        return te.articulo.Take(100).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Se te esta trabando en la pagina o el controlador?

Comment: ¿Realmente es necesario mostrar más de 100 registros a la vez? ¿Es una buena experiencia de usuario tener un listado de más de 100 registros en la pantalla? Creo que debes considerar la paginación de los registros.

Comment: por lo general no, pero ya para pasarlo a excel necesito mostrar los 3000 registros, como podria hacerlo para que no se cicle?

Comment: Podrías hacer uso de Ajax o PageMethods, ¿Lo has utilizado?

Comment: Hola, si e usado Ajax, el problema sigue siendo el mismo, el problema sigue siendo el mismo, es mucha informacion que traerme desde la base de datos, lo otro que se me ocurrio es solo mostrar toda la informacion al momento de imprimir el reportviwer pero no se como hacer eso

Comment: En el caso de generar un archivo de Excel con los 3,000 registros lo mejor es generar el archivo en el servidor y luego enviar el archivo en lugar de enviar los 3000 registros al cliente y generar el archivo en el cliente.

Comment: Gracias, buscare como se hace eso ahora, suena interesante

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar Un método async, el cual proporciona una manera cómoda de hacer el trabajo de larga duración sin bloquear el subproceso del llamador. El llamador de un método async puede reanudar el trabajo sin esperar a que el método async finalice. 
ejemplo :

```
    public async Task<"nombre de tu modelo"> ListaCompleta()
    {
        return View(await db.ListaCompleta.OrderByDescending(a => a.Articulo).ToListAsync());
    }
```